# Strange problem with Page Method JSON result

Tags: asp.net, javascript, json

I have the following JavaScript to populate a dropdown.  When I single step into `populateResourceList`, the value for `jsonList` is shown below the code.  However, this method fails on the `for` statement with the error *jsonList.Table is undefined*

What am I doing wrong?

```
function populateResourceList(jsonList) {
  var listItems = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonList.Table.length; i++) {
    listItems += "<option value='" + jsonList.Table[i].id + "'>" + jsonList.Table[i].name + "</option>";
  }
  $("#<%=resourceList.ClientID %>").html(listItems);
};

$(function() {
  var sessionId = 554;
  var x = PageMethods.GetFreeResources(sessionId, function(result, response, context) {
    populateResourceList(result);
  });
});
```

EDIT:
jsonList looks like this:

```
{
  "Table": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Billy Bester"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Marlene Smith"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "John Mills"
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Brady Kelly"
  }, {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Andrew Peel"
  }, {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Colin Clifford"
  }, {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "Kerri Steele"
  }, ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is a literal and not a string?

Try this and let me know. The eval is evil but it will tell us if this is the direction we want to go.

```
function populateResourceList(jsonList) {
    eval("var list=" + jsonList + ";");
    var listItems = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < list.Table.length; i++) {
        listItems += "<option value='" + list.Table[i].id + "'>" + list.Table[i].name + "</option>";
    }
    $("#<%=resourceList.ClientID %>").html(listItems);
};
```

Comment: What, the jsonList?  It's a string value, I just pasted it without quotes to be clear what quotes are actually part of it, and which surround it.

Comment: @ProfK - looks like you are using MSAJAX, which has Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer that you can use to deserialize json. A question could be asked: Why are you returning a string from your page method? just return the object and msajax will give you a javascript object on return? Am I missing something?

Comment: I return a string because I build my json as a string.  The serializer works great, thanks twice.